How to Efficiently Monitor and Log Memory Usage in a C#.NET Application?
I'm building a C#.NET app that handles a ton of data, and I want to keep track of how much memory it's eating up. This is to make sure it runs and doesn't hog resources. My app works on both regular PCs and servers so I need a solid way to monitor its memory use as time goes on. I'm after a strong solution that can handle this task . The goal is to have the app perform at its best and manage its resources . By tracking the memory, I can spot any issues early and fix them before they become big problems. This will help keep the app running , whether it's on someone's desktop or a big server somewhere.
Monitor memory usage metrics such as total memory allocated, current usage, and peak usage.
Log these metrics periodically or on specific events to analyze trends and identify potential memory leaks.
Implement a solution that minimizes performance overhead and integrates smoothly with existing logging frameworks (e.g., Serilog or NLog).
Handle different scenarios, such as desktop applications with UI interactions and server applications handling concurrent requests.
I've explored System.Diagnostics and performance counters, but I'm unsure about the best practices and potential pitfalls when implementing memory monitoring in C#.NET. Could someone provide guidance, code examples, or recommended libraries for efficiently monitoring and logging memory usage in a C#.NET application?

In visual studio> Debug> Performance Profile> check memory allocation and options
then launch the app and do the thing that make your app to leak memory, then stop it and the Performance Profile will give you a report of your objects.

Usually it is done via pretty standard combination of Grafana with OpenTelemetry and Prometheus.

@Behtash using VS here is not a production level scenario.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
